# what's the reason that the left ,right column always equal the center height

Tags: html, css

this is the code. the css:

```
#content{overflow:hidden;}

   .left{width:200px; margin-bottom:-200px;padding-bottom:200px; background:#cad5eb; float:left;}

   .right{width:400px; margin-bottom:-200px; padding-bottom:200px; background:#f0f3f9; float:right; }

   .center{margin:0 410px 0 210px; background:#ffe6b8; height:100px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">  
  <div class="left">hello</div>  
 <div class="right">right </div>  

  <div class="center">center</div>

</div>
```

what's the reason that the left ,right column always equal the center's height.if the margin-bottom:-200px;padding-bottom:200px value bigger than the center's height value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't, add borders and force `#content` to be very tall (to get around the `overflow:hidden`) and you'll see that `.left` and `.right` have the same height but `.center` is shorter:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/q27pf/

The `.left` and `.right` divs come out the same height because they both have one line of text with the same styling and the same `padding-bottom`.

Without an explicit height on `#content`, `#content` becomes tall enough to accommodate `.center`, the floating `.left` and `.right` are not considered when computing the height of `#content` because they're floating.

Comment: i am still confused, when i change the .left padding-bottom to 400px;why the right's  padding-bottom also change to 400px. the default's value 200px is useless

Comment: "he floating .left and .right are not considered when computing the height of #content because they're floating.“ can't unserstand this. there is to say if an element is floated, we will  not considered its height when computing the height ? am i right. if right, why can't considered its height

Comment: Padding is **inside** the element so going from 200px to 400px adds 200px to the element's height. Changing the padding-bottom on `.left` makes it "400px + one line of text" tall while `.right` stays "200px + one line of text" tall, `.right` doesn't change at all.

Comment: When an element is floated it is, essentially, removed from its parent element. So, when the parent's height is being computed, it behaves as though the floating elements weren't its children. I think you would benefit from some basic tutorials, google for "css float tutorial" and  you should find something.